# Segmentation fault while running MPI program with bash script

Tags: bash, mpi

I'm trying to write a simple script that will test my MPI application with different number of processes. 
Content of run.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
    echo "args required: <thread_count> <executable> <args>..."
    exit
fi

echo "
$@
$(date)">>result

TH_MAX=$1
THREAD=2
while [ $THREAD -le $TH_MAX ]; do
    echo $THREAD threads
    output=$(mpirun -np $THREAD ./$2 $THREAD ${@:3})
    echo $THREAD $output >> result
    let THREAD=THREAD+1
done
```

Now, when I was using it to run normal programs, everything was great. However, since I call mpirun I get segmentation fault.

Call:

```
./run.sh 2 main data_file 100
```

Result:

```
2 threads
[ubuntu:07144] *** Process received signal ***
[ubuntu:07144] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ubuntu:07144] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[ubuntu:07144] Failing at address: (nil)
[ubuntu:07144] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0) [0x7fc6359fccb0]
[ubuntu:07144] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fgets+0x1e) [0x7fc63569bfee]
[ubuntu:07144] [ 2] main(main+0x1f7) [0x400f6b]
[ubuntu:07144] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7fc63564e76d]
[ubuntu:07144] [ 4] main() [0x400cb9]
[ubuntu:07144] *** End of error message ***
```

I should mention that everything works perfectly when I call mpirun outside of script.

Comment: I tested your script on one of my mpi program...and it worked perfectly !

Comment: The error doesn't look like it is coming from the script, rather from the MPI program. Can you run the MPI program (arg 2, I'll call `foo`) just as `mpirun -np 2 ./foo` and whatever other arguments it needs? Do you need to specify a hostfile? You can do `set -x` in bash to display the command that will be executed.